# How to programmatically publish item in SiteCore 8.0 from Content Delivery Sever?

Tags: sitecore

In the production environment I want to publish user generated content from content delivery severs. I cannot access the master database directly.

I can create the item using Item Web API but I cannot find any example on how to publish the item.

Thanks

Comment: So in brief, you want to publish from CD to CM (web to master)

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not recommended to move content from master to web on CD server but you can do following.

You need to use sitecore.services.client api. More information on Client API can be found at https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/75/developer's_guide_to_sitecore.services.client_sc75-a4.pdf

Retrieve item by opening httpRequest

"http:///sitecore/api/ssc/item/?path={path}?database&language&version&includeStandardTemplateFields&includeMetadata&fields

Get the content the of master database. Then update it on web database something like this.

```
Database web = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
Database[] databases = new Database[1] { db };

Sitecore.Handle publishHandle = Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishItem(item, databases, db.Languages, true, false);
```

You need to fix the syntax, it is just direction.